After Applied Custom Colors to a ShowToastEvent in LWC in console log changing the color, how can change in LWC JS or CSS style how can we apply
This is the code what i have tried.
.slds-theme_success, .slds-theme--success {
   --slds-toast-color-background :rgb(29, 95, 216);
}


if (result.messageInSubscribe === 'Data Found in Both Master and Subscriber Orgs') {
    this.returningData = result.messageInSubscribe;
    console.log('Account data:', result.accountDataInSubscribe);
    const e = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Success!',
        message: 'Data Found in Both Master and Subscriber Orgs',
        variant: 'success',
        mode: 'sticky',
       
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(e);

